# What is this sort of signature in model theory?

Tags: notation, model-theory, modal-logic

I was browsing [this](https://nesinkoyleri.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ModalLogicLectureNotes.pdf) set of lecture notes for a mathematical introduction to modal logic. I'm not familiar with model theory, and the lecturers (who approach modal logic from a model-theoretic perspective) recursively define the well-formed formulae of *propositional unimodal logic* $\mathcal{L}$ as
$$\varphi::= p \;  \vert \; \top \; \vert \neg \varphi \; \vert \; \varphi \wedge \varphi \; \vert \; \Diamond\varphi$$

where $p$ varies over a countable set $P = \{ p, q, r ... \}.$ This is described as "the signature of propositional logic with the modal operator" which is fine and dandy. I understand 99% of this -- I know what a wff is, what a countable set is, what each of the symbols entail in logical expressions. What I don't know is exactly how the "signature" here works in a rigorous sense. Googling doesn't really help and I can't find anything of a similar notation or structure (to be fair, I don't know where to look or even what to search for.) I can understand intuitively what this means (I think!) -- $p$ is a wff, therefore so is $p \wedge p$, so is $\Diamond p$; and therefore so is $\top(p\wedge p)$, and $\neg \Diamond p$ and so on. I've just never encountered this way of defining a language and it seems so intuitive and useful I would very much like to know more.

Comment: I don't see why you think $\top(p\wedge p)$ is a wff.

Comment: It's concise way to specify formal syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form .

Comment: @ancientmathematician -- I feel like an idiot now. I thought that $\top$ was a predicate meaning "x is true" (as in the classic formulation of trivialism, $(\forall p)(Tp)$ which does *not* use the $\top$ symbol and I now see it is a constant.

Comment: @AlvaroP. -- thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: The thing that worries me about this spec of a language is that nowhere are the two parentheses mentioned. Without them I think that either $\lnot p\wedge p$ is ambiguous or we don't have the negation of $p\wedge p$ in the language. [I realise this is orthogonal to your concerns but it seems to me worth mentioning.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician -- BNF actually specifies syntax trees (recursively) rather than an ambiguous way to parse a string. So in your example  $(\lnot p) \land p$ and $\lnot (p \land p)$ correspond to two different trees (in the first, $\land$ is the root node, and in the second $\lnot$ is), so the grammar can correctly distinguish them. When writing things as a linear string, though, parentheses have to be inserted (or a priority assigned to each connective) in order to disambiguate which strings get sent to which tree. It's very common to leave this implicit.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for that very helpful clarification.